# NLP behind Google Assistant, Amazon Echo and Apple Siri

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot

How do these assisant based models analyse text and convert them to commands, I mean how do they understand the intent, property and value. I just want to know what are the models used and also I am trying to make a assistant bot, does anyone know a better model that can identify the command from the text given?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Transformer models such as Bert, Distilbert to build your own NLP engine.

To understand how to integrate these models to interpret the input query check this article:
https://ai-brewery.medium.com/simple-chatbot-using-bert-and-pytorch-part-1-2735643e0baa